# Bool operation in C#

Tags: c#, mvvm, mvvmcross

I have the following code which works as expected. I wonder how could I able to handle the `bool` operation. If `IsEnded` is true, I want to `EnrolledTimeFormatted` to return me `None`, if not then just return me that it returns now.

```
private bool _isEnded;
public bool IsEnded
{
  get
  {
    return _isEnded;
  }
  set
  {
     _isEnded = value;
     RaisePropertyChanged(() => IsEnded);
  }
}        

private DateTime _enrolledTime ;
public DateTime EnrolledTime
{
   get { return _enrolledTime ; }
   set
   {
      _enrolledTime = value;
       RaisePropertyChanged(() => EnrolledTimeFormatted);

    }
}

public string EnrolledTimeFormatted=> String.Format("{0:t}", EnrolledTime);
```

Comment: Why not `=> IsEnded ? "None" : String.Format(...)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to factor it in with a conditional expression:

```
public string EnrolledTimeFormatted => IsEnded ? "None" : $"{EnrolledTime:t}";
```

Since changing `_isEnabled` influences the value of `EnrolledTimeFormatted`, the setter for `IsEnded` should trigger property change for `EnrolledTimeFormatted` in addition for triggering the change of `IsEnded` itself.

**Note:** Since you are using C# 6 features anyway, you might as well use *interpolated strings* to shorten the expression.

Comment: Actually, you might as well write `EnrolledTime.ToString("t")`

Comment: @SLaks That's absolutely true. I like the new syntax because it is slightly shorter, but on the other hand, `ToString` call is slightly faster.

Answer (score 1):

A simple [ternary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx) will work.

```
public string  EnrolledTimeFormatted => 
    IsEnded ? "None" : String.Format("{0:t}", EnrolledTime);
```